# Update Unique Column partial string SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table that has a user names in the column. This is an example

```
| **Path**                           
| /test/path/Barry/home  
| /test/path/Jenny/home  
| /test/path/Jermehiam/home/Docs  
| /test/path/Sarah/home/Docs
```

I am not sure how to update just the part of the path that ends at 'home'. I need the other parts of the path to remain as the string I am replacing is with an environment variable. So the end result would be:

```
| **Path**                           
| ${PATH}  
| ${PATH}  
| ${PATH}/Docs  
| ${PATH}/Docs
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it in this way:

```
UPDATE PathTable
SET Path = '...'
WHERE Path LIKE '/test/path/%/home'

UPDATE PathTable
SET Path = '.../Docs'
WHERE Path LIKE '/test/path/%/home/Docs'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using SQL-Server you can use CHARINDEX(), SUBSTRING() and LEN()

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('home',url) = 0
            THEN url
            ELSE '${PATH}' + SUBSTRING(url, (CHARINDEX('home',url) + 4), LEN(url) - (CHARINDEX('home',url) + 3))
        END url
  FROM t_link
```

in Oracle, you can use INSTR(), SUBSTR() and LENGTH()

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('home',url) = 0
            THEN url
            ELSE '${PATH}' + SUBSTRING(url, (CHARINDEX('home',url) + 4), LEN(url) - (CHARINDEX('home',url) + 3))
        END url
  FROM t_link
```

Result

```
url
 **Path**                           
${PATH}
${PATH}
${PATH}/Docs
${PATH}/Docs
```

Comment: What if there happens to be a user named 'home'?